Use Maple to evaluate $\int\limits_{-r}^{0}\int\limits_{0}^{\theta}\sin(\xi)\cos(\theta)\delta(\theta+r)d\xi d\theta$
Consider the double integral
$$
\int\limits_{-r}^{0}\int\limits_{0}^{\theta}\sin(\xi)\cos(\theta)\delta(\theta+r)d\xi d\theta,
$$
where $r>0$. A back-of-the-envelope calculation gives the result $(1-\cos(r))\cos(r)$. I would like to use the symbolic mathematics package Maple to get the same result! I've tried, but Maple simply spits out the integral without evaluating it. All ideas and suggestions are welcome.

with Maple 2024.1 :
(int(int(sin(xi)*cos(theta)*Dirac(theta + r), xi = 0 .. theta), theta = -r .. 0) assuming (0 < r))

#cos(r)/2 - cos(r)^2/2

Or:
(int(sin(xi)*cos(theta)*Dirac(theta + r), [xi = 0 .. theta, theta = -r .. 0]) assuming (0 < r))

#cos(r)*(1 - cos(r))/2


Interesting. Maple seems to run into big issues when one tries to integrate something that involves multiple Dirac delta distributions. For example, this naive-looking integral is somehow a challenge to Maple: $\int\limits_{-r}^{0}\int\limits_{0}^{\theta}\left[\sin(\xi)\cos(\theta)\delta(\theta+r)+\sin(2\xi)\delta(\theta) \right]d\xi d\theta$. Any suggestions for this type of thing?
